# Erro ao migrar site WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, font

Bom Dia!

Galera, eu estava tentando migrar um site feito com WP para outro domínio, porém mesmo após mudar a url do banco ele continua direcionando para url antiga e apresenta o seguinte erro ao carregar as fontes

Access to Font at 'http://www.agenciagoup.com.br/projetos/sperone/wp-content/themes/sperone/fonts/GothamLight.woff' from origin 'http://sperone.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sperone.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

O CORS usa cabeçalhos HTTP para garantir o acesso à servidores diferentes do da origem do domínio. Como por exemplo quando você usa no seu CSS arquivos CDN.

No seu caso o acesso está sendo bloqueado. Para resolver isso de maneira simples, sem botar a mão no back-end, você pode seguir dois passos simples:

1. Baixe as fontes novamente e coloque na pasta do seu novo site *(você pode achar na pasta do antigo site)*.
2. Ajuste o CSS para pra que aponte para o diretório do novo site.